# Can sound be used for propulsion?

Tags: waves, acoustics, propulsion

I'm no physicist so this might seem absurd.

I Remember watching a cartoon as a kid where the character uses a powerful speaker to propel his cart and I was wondering if this was actually possible.

Being a highschooler I am aware to propel forward you shoot something backward.

So maybe in the case of a speaker it could "shoot out" sound waves?

Comment: This is similar to the Feynman Lawn Sprinkler problem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_sprinkler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a difficult question, even for people who are physicists. I say this after reading:

[https://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/hidden_sound.pdf](https://www.physics.princeton.edu/%7Emcdonald/examples/hidden_sound.pdf)

which discusses the concept of hidden momentum, a concept I've never heard of. Moreover, based on that article, it appears experts argue whether it does or does not exists in various circumstances.

The general idea is that sound waves move energy (density), $u$, at the speed of sound ($v$) in some direction, and that leads to an energy flux:

$$ \vec S = u\vec v $$

Following $E=mc^2$, we can turn that energy flux into a momentum:

$$ \vec p = \frac{\vec S}{c^2} = \frac{uv}{c^2} $$

which is tiny. It is in fact a relativistic effect, and is so tiny, that the author writes:

*"It appears that the fluid-dynamics community generally considers that the laws of relativity are not relevant to this branch of physics, and that the momentum density can and should be ignored"*

So the answer is "yes" if you're pedantic, and "no" if you are practical.

Comment: Relativity shows that the thrust must be $> 0$, but I strongly suspect that there is _more_ thrust possible here that comes from fluid dynamics itself, given that a fluid provides a reactive medium for thrusting against and each outward push of the speaker cone is thus essentially just like pushing off of a wall. The question is whether that the "suction" when the cone goes the _other_ way (almost) exactly cancels this out, or if flow/pressure equalization effects as air flows in from the sides alters the balance any.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Here is why:

When a loudspeaker is producing sound, it is pushing forward to produce the compression part of the wave in air, then it pulls backwards to produce the rarefaction part of the wave, then forward, then back, etc. This means there is no *net* force applied to the air from the cone and no *net* reaction thrust applied by the air to the cone. Your vehicle would just vibrate back and forth as the cone works back and forth and no propulsion would result.

Comment: Can it do it in pulses ?

Comment: @nielsnielsen Hmm.  Similarly, it could be argued that light from a laser can't produce thrust (and we know it can) - so I'm not convinced.  Imagine the loudspeaker backed by a sound-reflecting surface, so the initially backward-directed portion of the sound is directed forward (in phase with the forward sound).

Comment: As Carl Witthoft said, this problem seems similar to [Feynman's lawn sprinkler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_sprinkler), and if it is then the outward motion of the diaphragm will push the car forward more than the inward motion will pull it backward, because the air motion is focused in a narrower cone.

Answer (score -2):

Sure! Sound waves carry energy and momentum. So you could use a speaker like a very weak rocket. Totally impractical, though.

Comment: I'm not convinced (yet) by your text, because "sound" is reserved for a wave pattern, with both peaks and valleys.  I think you need to expand on the fact that the "push" is directed, while the "pull" draws air in from a hemisphere.  This is similar to Feynman's gedanken about a rotary lawn sprinkler being run in reverse (it doesn't move).